# When i use posix regex, regcomp pass regex_t* raise SIGSEGV

Tags: c, regex

here is my err code, when i use

```
#include <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
    regex_t *preg1;
    regcomp(preg1, "ab", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

it raise "SIGSEGV"

but when i use

```
#include <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
    regex_t preg2;
    regcomp(＆preg2, "ab", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

It work, my question is: I think &preg2, it's same with preg1, but why result is diff?

**update**: here is regcomp declaration

```
extern int regexec (const regex_t *__restrict __preg,
            const char *__restrict __string, size_t __nmatch,
            regmatch_t __pmatch[__restrict_arr],
            int __eflags);
```

Comment: `preg2` is a `regex_t`. `preg1` is a pointer to a `regex_t`. What is `preg1` pointing to?

Comment: `preg1` doesn't point to anything yet, that's why. `&preg2` points to `preg2` that's why that works.

Comment: You need to learn how pointers work. Also, turn on compiler warnings and *heed them*.  (Always use `gcc -Wall -Werror`)

Answer (score -1):

preg1 doesn't point to anything yet, that's why. &preg2 points to preg2 that's why that works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Haris, it's my question and my answer, I think this explaination is enough